# How to get next id of autogenerated field in laravel for specific table?

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking for something like :

```
DB::table('users')->getNextGeneratedId();
```

not

```
$user->save($data)
$getNextGeneratedId = $user->id;
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Which laravel are you using? Why did you tag all versions available?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.2. I taged all laravels because it is not laravel version specific question.

Comment: Things might have changed a little between `4` and `5` regarding Eloquent or Query Builder. You can try `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();` or if you're using `DB` facade to insert and then fetch the last inserted id: `DB::table('users')->insertGetId($user);`

Comment: I am using Model for insert,
DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId() gives me "0".

Answer (score 37):

This works for me:
(PHP: 7.0 - Laravel 5.5)

```
use DB;

$statement = DB::select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'users'");
$nextId = $statement[0]->Auto_increment;
```

Comment: it works PHP:8.0 Laravel:8.7

Comment: it works PHP:7.4.19 Laravel:8.83.3

Comment: MySQL will cache this info, so the number might not right. You change the MySQL caching time to zero, then it will be correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that the id you get is NOT BLOCKED!
Meaning if someone else inserts a user, that user will get the id you are working with.
i.e. you get an Auto_increment of 123 from the users table and create something else with an user_id of 123 before creating the user there is a chance that your user gets an id >123!

Comment: works for laravel 9 but for mysql 8.x you must query first $query = "SET @@SESSION.information_schema_stats_expiry = 0";  or you will get wrong number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283195/wrong-auto-increment-value-on-select

Answer (score 12):

You need to execute MySQL query to get auto generated ID.

```
show table status like 'users'
```

In Laravel5, you can do as following.

```
public function getNextUserID() 
{

 $statement = DB::select("show table status like 'users'");

 return response()->json(['user_id' => $statement[0]->Auto_increment]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For PostgreSQL:

```
<?php // GetNextSequenceValue.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

trait GetNextSequenceValue
{
    public static function getNextSequenceValue()
    {
        $self = new static();

        if (!$self->getIncrementing()) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Model (%s) is not auto-incremented', static::class));
        }

        $sequenceName = "{$self->getTable()}_id_seq";

        return DB::selectOne("SELECT nextval('{$sequenceName}') AS val")->val;
    }
}
```

The model:

```
<?php // User.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use GetNextSequenceValue;
}
```

The result:

```
<?php // tests/Unit/Models/UserTest.php

namespace Tests\Unit\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $this->assertSame(1, User::getNextSequenceValue());
        $this->assertSame(2, User::getNextSequenceValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the code snippet I used in Laravel which will work perfectly:

```
$id=DB::select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'Your table name'");
$next_id=$id[0]->Auto_increment;
echo $next_id;
```

Comment: Already suggested > 2 years prior. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43702149/

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel5, you can do as following.

```
$data = DB::select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'users'");

$data = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (array)$value;
}, $data);

$userId = $data[0]['Auto_increment'];
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can get auto generated id by this query.

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "databaseName"
AND TABLE_NAME = "tableName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$id = DB::table('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES')
    ->select('AUTO_INCREMENT as id')
    ->where('TABLE_SCHEMA','your database name')
    ->where('TABLE_NAME','your table')
    ->get();
```