# Wrong auto_increment value on select

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm running MySQL 8 and whenever I run

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table';
```

I get the wrong auto_increment value. Straightforward exemple :

```
ALTER TABLE test.lieux auto_increment = 6;

SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'lieux';
```

Return AUTO_INCREMENT of 4.

I even tried inserting a row after my auto_increment altering, it was indeed inserted with a PK value of 6, but the SELECT statement still returned me an A_I value of 4.

Is there something wrong with my schema or did I misunderstand the SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT statement ?

Comment: Try `SET @@SESSION.information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;` before `SELECT`. See [information_schema_stats_expiry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry).

Comment: @wchiquito That works ! But let me guess (I'm new to MySQL), '@@SESSION' means I have to run this command everytime I connect to MySQL. So either I do that in my server startup or maybe I can run the same command with '@@GLOBAL' at the beginning and never worry about it again ?
In any case, thanks a lot already :)

Comment: Effectively, the variable has Global and Session scope. You can also include it in your command line or in your MySQL config file. More details in the documentation.

Comment: Since information_schema_stats_expiry is for MySQL 8.0.3+, would there be any equivalent in MySQL 5.5 ? Or did MySQL 5.5 not cache information_schema and I don't have to change anything ?

Comment: `The information_schema_stats configuration option, introduced in MySQL 8.0.0, was removed and replaced by information_schema_stats_expiry.`, see [Changes in MySQL 8.0.3 (2017-09-21, Release Candidate)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-3.html). In previous versions, I understand that this functionality did not exist.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the table statistics are cached beginning with Mysql 8.

To see the current value of the cache, execute -

```sql
show variables like 'information_schema_stats_expiry'

/* output (For mysql 8+, default cache is  86400 seconds = 1 day) */
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| information_schema_stats_expiry | 86400 |
+---------------------------------+-------+
```

To get the latest `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, you should update the expiry time to bypass the cache.
There are 2 ways you can do this.

##### 1. For the current session

To update the cache value for the current session alone, as suggested in the comments, execute

```sql
SET @@SESSION.information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
```

##### 2. Globally

If you wish to disable the cache altogether, use

```sql
SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0
```

---

IMO, a default cache of 1 day is an overkill and totally unneeded. A cache of about 5 mins (300s) should generally suffice.

[Offical Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry)