# MySQL insert with this increment id

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `logs` table, which contains `id`, `log_string`, and `created_at`.

DDL for `logs`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `log_string` varchar(255) NULL,
    `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The `log_string` column is by concat `id` and `created_at` and some string, and I do this by doing twice insert:

```php
$log = App\Log::create(); //insert at the first time
$logString='This is log '.$log->id.'('.$log->created_at.')';
$log->update(['log_string'=>$logString]); //insert at the 2nd time
```

Could it possible to do that by just insert once?

There is a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in MySQL but no `THIS_INSERT_ID()`, any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next id of autogenerated field in laravel for specific table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210747/how-to-get-next-id-of-autogenerated-field-in-laravel-for-specific-table)

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the next insertion id and the time stamp when the next log entry will be created (created_at). So, in other words, you want to have future entries :)

So no it is not possible. You can predict it by looking what's the current id is and increment it by 1 yourself because that is what going to be the next log id probably. But this approach is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED because if you are managing this table logic in more than one place, you never know what is going to be the next id as many scripts will be changing the table on the various time interval.

So no there is no way to do it in one query. However, you could write a cron which fills out the `log_string` column once in a day or so like:

```
UPDATE logs SET log_string = CONCAT("This is log ", id, "(", created_at, ")") WHERE log_string IS NULL;
```

I have not tested the query, it is just to give you an idea.

This way you don't need to run an extra query every single time. You just do it, once a day or so for a bunch of entries.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want, however it isn't possible in a convenient way. But more importantly it isn't necessary as you already have ID in your table.

You can format it via `sprintf` when you print the log.

```
sprintf('This is log %s (%s)', $id, $date);
```

However, if you still insist on hardcoding the ID in log message you can use [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) to pre-generate the ID.

Another option is to utilize a messaging queue to update message in log table as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is AUTO INCREMENT, then it would be impossible to achieve what you want without at least two requests.

---

However, it would be interested if you add a *custom attribute* to your model and remove log_string from the table:

#### Update your table

Remove *log_string* column

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

#### Update your model

Then add the custorm attribute to App\Log.php

```php
/**
 * Custom attribute for log_string
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogStringAttribute()
{
    return "This is log {$this->id} ({$this->created_at})";
}
```

#### Access to data

```php
$log = App\Log::create(); //insert at the first time
$log->save(); // save the model to get the id and create_at datas
echo $log->log_string; // display the log string
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the ["Observer"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers)

something like that:

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Log;

class LogObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Log "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Log  $log
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Log $log)
    {
        $log->log_string = $log->id . ' (' . $log->created_at . ')';
        $log->save();
    }
```