# Access an ID of a record before its finished being created laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to store the id of a record within the record. I am aware I could just use a where statement to find the last ID and increment by one but I was curious is it possible to get the ID of the record whilst its been made.

```
$ScreenshotOBJ = Screenshots::create([
                   "CollectionID" => $ScreenshotOBJ->id,
//This isn't the whole record just the important part
                ]);
```

Is this possible it throws an error saying the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: You can technically [get the next ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210747/how-to-get-next-id-of-autogenerated-field-in-laravel-for-specific-table) But I'm not sure why you need that. What are you trying to do with that ID?

Comment: The records need to be grouped as a collection, so im using the first record as the collection id. I was curious was this possible i could add extra code which im fine adding just seems hacky and i wasn't sure was it possible to get the id whilst the record is being created

Comment: If you want to group few records, you should probably define a hasMany relation to self on the model and then have a column as say parent_id to the table and link records to be grouped by putting the id of parent record in the parent_id column for the records to be group with the parent record.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `CollectionID` field nullable. And then in the boot method of your `Screenshots` model, you can set the `CollectionID` like this,

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function ($screenshot) {
        $screenshot->update(
            ['CollectionID' => $screenshot->id)]
        );
    });
}
```